# Possible to switch SonarQube Analyzer from Maven to Sonar-Runner?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I currently analyze a multi-module java project with sonarqube 4.3 using maven. The structure of the analysis´ configuration is:

```
root-pom.xml
 -module1
  --module1-pom.xml
 -module2
  --module2-pom.xml
```

So what I did was rebuilding the whole configuration in 1 sonar-project.properties following the **multi-module Project** Section of [this documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner)

It is most important to me, that I can continue with my historical data, false-positives etc.

Currently, I am experimenting with a test system. It seems to be possible to just switch the analyzer, keeping the old data.

What I ask for, is some reassurance or a link to a documentation how to switch between analyzers. Thanks.

**UPDATE concerning controlling the keys:**

My root-pom.xml defines the key as

`<groupId>de.company</groupId>
 <artifactId>product</artifactId>`

The module-pom.xmls define the modules´s key as:

`<groupId>de.company</groupId>
 <artifactId>module1</artifactId>`

My new sonar-project.properties for switching to sonar-runner looks loke this:

```
 sonar.projectKey=de.company:product
 sonar.modules=module1, module2

 module1.sonar.projectKey=de.company:module1
 module2.sonar.projectKey=de.company:module2
```

With that configuration, it seems to be possible to continue the analysis of the maven analysis with sonar-runner.

Answer (score 2):

@Tim, with Sonar Runner you can't drive the way SonarQube generate the keys for each module so you won't be able to have the same keys used by the Maven SonarQube Runner. And so you will lose your false-positives, historical data, configuration ...

Comment: Thank you for your response, Freddy. Let me get back on that subject after my vacation in 3 weeks. I will edit my question and try to provide more relevant detail.

Comment: I updated my question with the configuration for controlling the module-keys